# padding more or equal const value (padding >= value)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I try to use flexbox and I want to make div the same height. but my middle div in first row a bit more than others. 
That is my result:
[image]

That what they want (midlle in the first row has paddig-bottom:24px and other have more, so they could be on the same level when align-items:flex-end)
[image]

That is my code where .image-container is a div in which image and description
[image]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're using vertical flex-box. Based on the layout you don't need that. Just create a flex row for the cells with a wrap. The elements will always be the height of the tallest one on the same line.

```css
.imageGrid {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row; /* you don't need this since its the default */
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.gridItem {
  background-color: #dadada;
  flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 24px);
  margin-right: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageGrid">
  <div class="gridItem">
    <p>stuff</p>
  </div>
  <div class="gridItem">
    <p>stuff</p>
    <p>Make this one taller with added stuff</p>
  </div>
  <div class="gridItem">
    <p>stuff</p>
  </div>
  <div class="gridItem">
    <p>stuff</p>
  </div>
  <div class="gridItem">
    <p>stuff</p>
  </div>
  <div class="gridItem">
    <p>stuff</p>
  </div>

</div>
```